# Let minimum_should_match only apply to subset of should clauses

Tags: elasticsearch

In a `bool` query, I am trying to match documents that either match `field1` or any 2 of `{field2, field3, field4}`. I know that I can achieve the second condition with `minimum_should_match: 2` but how do I make sure that the `should` clause for `field1` is excluded from the minimum_should_match?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query as a bool containing two queries:

- A match query for the field1
- A bool query containing a multi match for fields 2,3 and 4 in the must section, and a must_not exluding the field1.

Here is an example:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field1": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "value",
                  "fields": [
                    "field2",
                    "field3",
                    "field4"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "value"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```